# select a random button from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray

I have to hide one of mine four UIButtons, randomly selected, BUT Excepting one.

for this, I created a NSMutableArray, and added all button there, as following example:

```
rand_btns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: _bt1, _bt2, _bt3, _bt4,nil];
```

No, each button has its own tag: **_bt1** has **tag 1**, _bt2 has tag 2, and so...

Please, any ideas? I want to hide one random button, but excepting a button which has tag equal to my: **int Level**.

I want to use this for a Quiz App.

So, my int Level is from 1-4 random number, when one of mine four buttons has tag equal to mine **int Level**, that button should be excepted from hiding.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)randomSelForLevel:(NSInteger)level
{
    int randomTag = rand() % 4;
    while (randomTag == level) {
        randomTag = rand() % 4;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[rand_btns count]; i++) {
        [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:NO];
    }
    [[rand_btns objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: instead of "int randomTag = rand () % 4;" what should i put to avoid repeating random number?

Comment: Store the current selection in a variable and next time check it before doing the remaining

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
int randomTag = rand() % 4;
while (randomTag == Level) {
    randomTag = rand() % 4;
}
[[randButtons objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:YES]
```

Comment: [randButtons objectAtIndex:randomTag].hidden = YES; - this line doesn't work/recognized

Comment: Try [[randButtons objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:YES]

Comment: How are you setting up the buttons that you're adding?

Comment: using interface builder

Comment: now works, but... i have to call twice or more that method to hide a random button.

Comment: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

I thinks should be rand () % 3 + 1 not 4 + 1. What do you think?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking it was the tag thing, which starts at 1, but it's the index, which you're right, begins at 0.

Comment: Great... It also, hides that specific button :( i have 4 buttons, when my level is 3 for example, this mean that button with tag 3 can't be hidden using that code...

Answer (score 0):

to select random no between two no use this code:
int random = lowno + arc4random() % (highno-lowno);
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
abarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ab = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    ab = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    ab.tag = i;

   [ab setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",ab.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [ab addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [ab sizeToFit];

    ab.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [abarr addObject:ab];

    [self.view addSubview:ab];

    switch (ab.tag) {

        case 0:
            ab.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50);
            break;

        case 1:
            ab.frame=CGRectMake(50, 0, 50,50);
            break;

        case 2:
            ab.frame=CGRectMake(100, 0, 50,50);
            break;

        case 3:
            ab.frame=CGRectMake(150, 0, 50,50);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}

randomTag = rand() % 4;

for (int i=0; i<[abarr count]; i++) {
    [[abarr objectAtIndex:randomTag] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
[[abarr objectAtIndex:randomTag] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

-(void)clicked:(UIButton*)button
 {

  NSLog(@"%ld",(long int)[button tag]);

     for (int i=0; i<[abarr count]; i++) 
 {
     [[abarr objectAtIndex:randomTag] setHidden:YES];
    }


 }
```